# Ionic - build/run for browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a ionic app (current version) that I have built and its now running on my local dev server just fine. I needed to add Strip Payment integration so I included the cordova-stripe-plugin (https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-stripe#module_stripe). I can not test because ionic serve doesn't include the cordova.js, etc.
**I have looked high and low and can not find any definitive information or guide on how to run/build this app for mobile browser/web/PWA.** There is conflicting information. Can you please clarify and provide the command lines to run to build/run and Ionic app that I can deploy to my webserver. Also, what about testing? will I have to rebuild every time I need to make a change or is there a some sort of live reload I can use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When i start to learn ionic, i have same question with you. Now, I still accept the answer that if you want to test a function use cordova, you must run app in a device or simulator. Live reload does not work on device. So to save your time, develop as much as you can in the browser, only test native function in browser

Comment: @Duannx while this is true for some cordova plugins, it's not true for all. Many cordova plugins are built for the browser as well as iOS and cordova. You can build progressive apps using cordova if you use the right plugins

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Build for Browser

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic cordova build browser --prod
```

For testing on browser just use ionic serve, every time you update code, it will auto rebuild.

Comment: May be these one ionic  platform add browser
ionic build browser --prod

Comment: These build for the Cordova browser platform, which isn't (currently) supported by Ionic and not recommeded. Instead you should build the app outside of Cordova using `ionic build --prod` and serve the `www` folder.

Comment: 'ionic serve' doesn't run from the built browser platform - that's running a separate build. 'ionic cordova run browser' is the correct command.

Comment: `ionic build browser --prod` this command only required if you've already installled platform browser

Answer (score 11):

To build app,

```
ionic cordova build browser
```

To run app,

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

Before run/build run this command on your terminal.

```
npm serve
```

If you are working with a git repository please make sure to get pulls before you start coding and before you commit your code.

Comment: the part about git is so unrelated.. also feels like npm has nothing to do here